# Calculating cycles/byte from QueryPerformanceCounter()

Tags: c, performance, winapi, intrinsics, avx2

I have made a bit sliced implementation of the PRIMATEs cipher found here: http://primates.ae/ (I made it of the 120-bit version).

I made it solely in C and used Intel Intrinsics, such that I could use the AVX2 instruction set.

Since I made a bit sliced implementation, I have wanted to optimize it for speed and thus to measure the performance, I calculate the cycles per byte. For this, I use the QueryPerformanceCounter() function provided by Windows

The thing is now. In my calculations, I arrive at using 1,91 cycles per byte, which seems *reeeaaally* good. I feel like I must be doing something wrong (I am not THAT good of a coder). This is how I do it:

```
//Size of testdata
int testDataSize = 4000; //bytes

//Get CPU frequency (cycles per sec)
LARGE_INTEGER start, finish;
double cpu_frequency;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&start);
cpu_frequency = (double)(start.QuadPart)

QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
encrypt(data);
decrypt(data);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&finish);

double cyclesUsed = (double)(finish.QuadPart - start.QuadPart);
double bytesSecond = (cpu_frequency / cyclesUsed) * testDataSize;
double bytesCycle = bytesSecond / cpu_frequency;
double cycles_per_byte = 1 / bytesCycle;
```

During runtime, the cycles spent between the two QueryPerformanceCounter calls (i.e. the time encrypting and decrypting) is the delta between **start** and **finish**, which is about 7674 cycles. This is the time for 4000 bytes.

Naturally, I would then be using just about 1.9 cycles per byte, but this seems really good... Have I implemented the cycles/byte calculations correctly and have I understood the use of QueryPerformanceCounter() correctly? Or am I computing some random number right now.

Also, in case somebody knows: Is this a realistic value in general for encrypting/decrypting data with modern ciphers? I know this is subjective to the area and hard to answer, but worth a shot... In either case, whether I have implemented it correctly is what I am most interested in knowing right now, since I can see my test-vectors passes with these results.

I do the tests with Intel TurboBoost turned off, and with just 1 CPU core.... I cannot turn hyperthreading off (thank you simplified Lenovo BIOS), but I doubt it would do a difference, since my code is singlethreaded.

Comment: You might want to use rdtsc

Comment: Thanks. I just learned a hard-learned lesson by not doing so, and will do so from now on. __rdtsc seems useful, will give it a check!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is right, but you are misinterpreting the data. `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` doesn't give you the CPU frenquency, it gives you the performance counter frequency. This means that you are counting in term of arbitrary ticks, and not cycles. There is no easy way to get the cycle count with Windows performance counters (CPU frequency is often dynamic), but you can get a decent execution time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I did figure that something was off here. Glad to have it clarified.
QueryPerformanceFrequency in my case returns 2533192.00. If my CPU is 2.533Ghz (Turbo boost turned off, so it's stable at that value), would that mean that my calculations are a factor 1000 off?

Comment: @oPolo Yes, probably. Performance counters are only good at measuring time, so you should calculate throughput (MB/s). I'm removing the "usually 100MHz" part, it seems I'm confusing with something else.

Comment: The actual perf counter hardware can and does measure core clock cycles, not TSC cycles.  Don't get that mixed up with the naming of some Windows functions.  IDK how you'd do it on Windows, but on Linux you can run `perf stat ./a.out` and see how many core clock cycles your whole program took.

Comment: @ElderBug The `cpu_clk_thread_unhalted.ref_xclk` performance event ticks at precisely 100MHz on Haswell, but you might as well use the fixed-function unhalted reference and/or unhalted core cycle counters, from which you can derive both bytes/second and (what matters more) bytes per cycle with in excess of nanoprecision accuracy, given that they count at CPU nominal and boosted frequencies respectively.